# Are there AdS/CFT duals all the way down?

Tags: ads-cft

Last night I was thinking about the AdS/CFT correspondence, and I thought of the following scenario:

Consider a 4D AdS universe with only a single black hole. Assuming the bulk and boundary are perfectly dual, then we expect just a single black hole on the 3D boundary right? But if we invoke the holographic principle then all of the information of the black hole is somehow related to the surface area, which is only 2D.

So my question is this: If we consider a static universe, are there dualities that we can keep invoking all the way down to 1D or 0D, or up to higher dimensions?

*Please let me know if this is a poorly posed question, or, a reference to read if this is easily answered (I do not have much training in physics).*

Comment: In the standard AdS/CFT holography the CFT side does not have gravity, so there would be no 3D black hole.

Comment: @A.V.S. ohh interesting! I was under the impression that the CFT side was supposed to correspond with our universe more directly. I also found a similar question since I posted, but I can't vote to close since the question is in answered - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/708864/ads-cft-correspondance-from-1d-to-4d?rq=1